# What are the best resources to learn Polymer?

Tags: polymer, web-component

Web Components is the next big thing to change the web.

I am amazed by the power of web components and the best way to make an web components is the Polymer.

What are the best resources to learn Polymer? Can we put all the resources together?

Comment: I like this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-web-application-polymer-material-design — But watch out! Polymer v2 is around the corner: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20

Comment: I see many fancy answers here… But I dont think none of it has plain explanation. Please go through this blog. It is very plain and simple and help you get started with polymer 3 & lit-html... https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/category/polymer-3/

Answer (score 6):

The Best Resources I found till now:

https://github.com/polymer

http://www.polymer-project.org/

http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/distributing-components-with-bower.html

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer

http://addyosmani.com/blog/webapps-yeoman-polymer/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/yeoman/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OJ7ih8EE7s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKrYfrAzqFA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-Zq2KUN6jM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRbOSdAe_JU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eORqFaf_QzM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75EuHl6CSTo&list=PLy1YG3u6yVCRuaxVRRZw7-vv3VxY2Vhk6

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMVj_jR75vE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FarTf5P8Wsg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rz334A8U7o

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QLmAm9xtnU

Comment: webcomponents.org (esp. webcomponents.org/articles and webcomponents.org/presentations)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ebidel/6314025 is a comprehensive list of resources.

Comment: Adding my part :)   http://itshackademic.com/

Comment: We are aggregating the best Polymer tutorials here: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-polymer. Can I request the Polymer community to add the tutorials they have found useful there and upvote as well? Thanks.